# publishing to github (angular project)

Tags: angular, github, deployment

I'm having some problems seeing the web homepage my Angular 5 project to GitHub (I'm currently doing a boot-camp course on angular). I'm running it on my local machine using a node server and using Git Bash.  When I first published it to GitHub I could see my project clearly then I added some routing and the published page no longer appears in the 2nd version.  Is this because I'm only allowed one website on GitHub or something different entirely.

My project can be found at https://github.com/black-tomcat-dev/edureka-angular  However I cannot see the published page @--> https://black-tomcat-dev.github.io/edureka-angular/  is this url incorrect.

The steps I took was the following

```
       1) ng build --prod  (to build production mode angular project).
       2) npm install -g -angular-cli-gh-pages.
       3) git init or if already installed move to next step.
       4) git add .
       5) git commit -m "first commit"
       6) git remote add origin "https://github.com/black-tomcat-dev/"
       7) git push -u origin master
       8) ng build --prod --base-href="https://black-tomcat-
                                           dev.github.io/edureka-angular"
       9) angular-cli-ghpages
```

Step 9 says successfully published but when I open the url the website is blank and inspecting the script says it cannot find bundle.css, bundle.js etc.

Why are the compressed bundles not being picked up by my published pages? I'm getting no errors from building my project and putting it in dist folder.

Something trivial I'm missing to viewing a live version of index.html